# Вызов hotKey в программе

Tags: javascript, jquery

Дополняю текстовый редактор, в котором есть hotKey( Shift + Ctrl + B), который выделяет текст. Можно ли как-то вызвать эту функцию из программы? Понимаю, что нужно найти скрипт, который делает действие при нажатие данной комбинации, но может кто-то делал что-то подобное. Условно, мне нужно примерно следующее:

`call_hotkey("Shift + Ctrl + B")` - результат выделенный текст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имитация нажатия при клике:

```js
call_hotkey("Control", "Shift", "B");

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  call_hotkey("Control", "Shift");
});

function call_hotkey(...params) {
  for (let key of params) {    
    document.dispatchEvent( new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': key}) );
  }
  
  setTimeout(function() {    
    for (let key of params) {    
      document.dispatchEvent( new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'key': key}) );
    }
  }, 50);
}

/*** Некая реализация клавиш где-то внутри */
(function() {
  let pressed = [];

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log("keydown", e.key);
    
    pressed.push(e.key);
    if (pressed.length > 2) pressed.shift();
    
    if (pressed.join(" ") === "Control Shift") {
      console.log("moo");
    }
  });
  
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    console.log("keyup", e.key);
    
    let index = pressed.indexOf(e.key);    
    if (index > -1) pressed.splice(index, 1);
  });
})();
```

У меня реализация привязана к `e.key`, поэтому здесь передача единственного параметра `{'key': key}` в конструкторе `new KeyboardEvent` работает. Если заранее не знать, как оно реализовано внутри, нужно подсмотреть и передать все внутренности настоящего события:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Возможно, еще и запускать `keypress`, чтобы наверняка.